# Macro Do loop until in sas

Tags: sas

I want to find the relationship of  O & H  or H & O in E1-E6. THEN the output is R6=S6-S5 else R6=S6-S4, else  R6=S6-S3 else R6=S6-S2 until we find the relationship, else 0;It should repeat the same way for R5=S5-S4 else R5=S5-S3, else  R5=S5-S2 else R5=S5-S1

```
SL  E1  E2  E3  E4  E5  E6  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6
1   O   H                   1   4               
2   R   H   O   H           1   6   4   8       
3   O   O   H   O   O   H   2   4   6   7   9   8
4   H   O   R   H   O   H   4   5   4   5   8   7
5   O   O   O   H   H   O   3   5   6   7   7   5
6   O   O   H               2   4   7           
7   H   R   H   O           3   5   6   9       
8   O   H   H   R   O   H   6   7   8   8   6   9
9   O   R   H   H   R       4   7   8   9       
10  R   H   R   O   H       5   8   4   8   9
```

Typo mistake, Edited. If E6=E5 as OH or HO relation then R6=S6-S5 else S6-S4. To find untill relationship then E5=E4 as OH or HO relation then R5=S5-S4 else S5-S3...,. If HHRO then substract O of S column with next of H column of S, Then there is no need of doing for another H.

```
Example output edited

   SL   R2  R3  R4  R5  R6
1   3               
2       -2  4       
3       2       3   -1
4   1       1   3   -1
5           1       -2
6       3           
7           3       
8   1           -2  3
9               5   
10          0   1
```

Comment: Your rules don't entirely make sense.  Can you explain what is really happening here?  Why are you choosing to subtract S3-S2 but not S3-S1 for the 3rd row, for example?  Why is R4 populated with 1 for SL=4?  And to be clear, you always subtract the lower E# from the higher E#, regardless of which is H or O?

Comment: always subtract the lower E# from the higher E# where O is next relation with H then next relation with O then H, If HHROOH then H-O,Next O-H suppressing O R and next H suppress last H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the precise rules are, you don't want to use a macro for this.  You want to use a pair of arrays.

```
data have;
infile datalines missover;
input
SL  E1  $ E2 $  E3 $ E4 $ E5  $ E6 $ S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6
;
datalines;
1   O   H   X   X   X   X   1   4               
2   R   H   O   H   X   X   1   6   4   8       
3   O   O   H   O   O   H   2   4   6   7   9   8
4   H   O   R   H   O   H   4   5   4   5   8   7
5   O   O   O   H   H   O   3   5   6   7   7   5
6   O   O   H   X   X   X   2   4   7           
7   H   R   H   O   X   X   3   5   6   9       
8   O   H   H   R   O   H   6   7   8   8   6   9
9   O   R   H   H   R   X   4   7   8   9       
10  R   H   R   O   H   X   5   8   4   8   9   
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have;
array e e1-e6;
array s s1-s6;
array r r2-r6;
matchfound=0;
do _t = dim(s) to 2 by -1;
  do _u = _t-1 to 1 by -1 until (matchfound); *iterate over each lower value of e[];
    *put _n_= e[_t]= e[_u]= _t= _u=;  *uncomment for debugging;
    if cats(e[_t],e[_u]) in ('HO','OH') then do; *if OH or HO;
      matchfound=1;  *set match found so we leave the inner loop;
      r[_t-1] = s[_t] - s[_u]; *calculate R;
    end;
  end;
  if _u >= 1 then _t = _u+1;   *u+1 because it is decremented one time too many automatically;
  else if matchfound=1 then leave;  *if _u =0 and matchfound=1 then we matched the final (u=1);
  matchfound=0; *reset for next lower check;
end;
run;
```

That probably needs tweaking but should roughly give you the structure to work from.